# Socket.io multiple pages

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat

I'm trying to create a chat using socket.io, I'm having a problem.

I want to know if it is possible to reuse my socket.id in my different pages of my project to not lose the connection of my socket?

Comment: can you post a minimal example of your code?

Comment: do socket io from a worker.  worker has state. multiple pages can msg back n forth to worker .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A given socket.io connection belongs only to one particular page.  When the user browses to a new page (assuming you're not dynamically loading new content into the same master page using a single-page-app (SPA) architecture), that socket.io connection is closed and the new page can then open a new socket.io connection (that will have a different socket.id).

> I want to know if it is possible to reuse my socket.id in my different pages of my project to not lose the connection of my socket?

No, not when the browser is actually loading a whole new page into the current window/tab.

---

The usual way to create some sort of ID that is persistent when you go from one page to the next is to put an ID in a cookie and then that cookie will be available on each new page the user browses to and will stay consistent from one page to the next.

If you are using express on the server, you can use express-session to automatically create a persistent session for each new user and you can even store data in that session object that will be available on each page the user requests.

Answer (score 2):

on page refresh and navigation your socket will get disconnected so you can use this trick.it worked in my scenario

suppose you have a multi-page application then ,here you can do a trick that when your socket gets connected first time when the page loads then you can assign the session id to that particular connection like this.and then bind that connection to that session.

```
 io.on('connection', function(socket) {

 socket.on('start-session', function(data) {
            console.log("============start-session event================")
            console.log(data)
            if (data.sessionId == null) {
                var session_id = uuidv4(); //generating the sessions_id and then binding that socket to that sessions 
                socket.room = session_id;
                socket.join(socket.room, function(res) {
                    console.log("joined successfully ")
                    socket.emit("set-session-acknowledgement", { sessionId: session_id })


            } else {
                socket.room = data.sessionId;  //this time using the same session 
                socket.join(socket.room, function(res) {
                    console.log("joined successfully ")
                    socket.emit("set-session-acknowledgement", { sessionId: data.sessionId })
                })
            }
        });
```

Now you had binded the socket connection to a session now you are sending an acknowledgement too at the client side also .There what you can do is that store the session id to the web browsers session storage like this

At client side code

```
 socket.on("set-session-acknowledgement", function(data) {
  sessionStorage.setItem('sessionId', data.sessionId);

 })
```

This will store the session id in the browsers session storage.Now when the page is navigated from page1 to page2 and so on. then send that session id to the server so that you will be connected to the same session logically like this

```
  var session_id;
            // Get saved data from sessionStorage
            let data = sessionStorage.getItem('sessionId');
            console.log(data)
            if (data == null) {
                session_id = null//when we connect first time 
                socket.emit('start-session', {  sessionId: session_id })
            } else {
                session_id = data//when we connect n times 
                socket.emit('start-session', {  sessionId: session_id })
            }
```

So basically the logic behind is that we can use same session for multiple socket connections by doing this as every time the socket will be joined to that particular room only and emit the events which you can listen on server side and vice a versa.